# Cheking if "admin" or "user" using fetch in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

i need to verify when the user longin (using fetch API) if role == "admin" or "user" using token.
if role == "admin" then make a redirection to /accounts for example, otherwise if it's a "user" then hide the authentication form in render and make some animation (css / js) on the page if it's possible to hide other things when it's a simple user and not an Admin.

This is my code 
Here is the result of a good Admin auth,
the token here is "result" :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "result": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.ZuNdWcWfu-J_dvgCmUH_w8EAx4FIeSMvAqG8ebm1ilc"
}
```

The auth of simple User is the same, there is only the token that changes
There is my fetch API for login :

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cnx_mail: '',
      cnx_pwd: '',
      items: [],
      token : '',
      errors: {},

      formErrors: {cnx_mail: '', cnx_pwd: ''},
      emailValid: false,
      passwordValid: false,
      formValid: false
    }
     this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch(`${API}/api/connexion`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
          },
        body: JSON.stringify ({
            email: this.state.cnx_mail,
            password: this.state.cnx_pwd,
          })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        localStorage.setItem('toktok', json.result);
        // Redirect here if Admin  this.props.history.push('/accounts');  Else hide the authentication form in render()      

    }); 
  }
```

My auth form in render() > hide it when role == user:

```
<form className="demoForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate  encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                                <div className="alreadysubscribed-input">
                                    <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_mail)}`}>
                                        <input type="email" required className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_mail"
                                            value={this.state.cnx_mail}
                                            id="cnx_mail"
                                            onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_mail} />
                                            <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_mail">Email</label>
                                            <div className="fatb-bar"></div>                                  
                                    </div>

                                    <div className={`alreadysubscribed-field group-input ${this.errorClass(this.state.formErrors.cnx_pwd)}`}>
                                        <input type="password" required className="form-control fatb-input input-form" name="cnx_pwd"
                                            value={this.state.cnx_pwd}
                                            id="cnx_pwd"
                                            onChange={this.handleUserInput} error={errors.cnx_pwd} />
                                            <label className="fatb-label" htmlFor="cnx_pwd">Mot de passe</label>
                                            <div className="fatb-bar"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <FormErrors formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />

                                <div className="btn-cnx">
                                    {/* <span className="mas">Se connecter</span> */}
                                    <button className="fatb-btn bubbly-button btn-anim3 w100p" type="submit"  name="cnx_btn" disabled={!this.state.formValid}>se connecter</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: I think your question is pretty vague here. What specifically isn't working?

Comment: it's workign, but i need to hide the form auth when it's a simple User, and make a redirection to another page if it's an Admin

Comment: OK, so how would the code in `handleSubmit` know if the user is admin or not?

Comment: there is a token

Comment: yes, there is a token - so? how does the token help *you* decide if the user is admin or not?

Comment: that's what I want to know, otherwise there is the account table in DB  that contains all the fields, but i don't know how to use it here to get the role field

Comment: the account table? fields? what are these things? They aren't mentioned in the question

Comment: i just answered your question

Comment: in which part of code i can put that code please ?

Comment: yes, because i need other fetch(/api/accounts) to do that i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you check for the `role` in the token

```js
// fake the result:
var json = {
    result: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.ZuNdWcWfu-J_dvgCmUH_w8EAx4FIeSMvAqG8ebm1ilc"
};

// this one line is your answer
const isAdmin = JSON.parse(atob(json.result.split('.')[1])).account[0].role === 'admin';

// 
console.log(isAdmin);
```

> ### A warning

the token payload is as follows

```
{
  "account": [
    {
      "dateCreation": "2019-10-24T10:32:30.730Z",
      "resetpasswordtoken": null,
      "resetpasswordexpires": null,
      "role": "admin",
      "enable": true,
      "_id": "5db17f863faf3f1154479ee6",
      "email": "saaraaaachemlal@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$lFIJJAPWReZgC/MjDhbnHecS7FowwA9TSjLNTfUwQXJPvX0NhCMwu",
      "tickets": [],
      "gains": [],
      "__v": 0,
      "nom": "ACHEMLAL_",
      "prenom": "MERYEM_",
      "tel": "0619562721"
    }
  ],
  "iat": 1572043952
}
```

There's a LOT of personal information in that!!! i.e. one field of personal information would be too much

Comment: it's just a test :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your token is in the format of a JWT, or "JSON Web Token."

First of all, a caveat: it's super dangerous to expose JWTs through an API like this. It's far preferable to keep JWTs transfering around via secure, HTTP-only cookies. If a bad player acquires this JWT token, they can perform tasks on behalf of the user.

That being said, if you insist on exposing the user's token to the browser, know that JWTs can be decoded to expose their payload. The JWT you posted here has this payload:

```
{
  "account": [
    {
      "dateCreation": "2019-10-24T10:32:30.730Z",
      "resetpasswordtoken": null,
      "resetpasswordexpires": null,
      "role": "admin",
      "enable": true,
      "_id": "5db17f863faf3f1154479ee6",
      "email": "saaraaaachemlal@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2b$10$lFIJJAPWReZgC/MjDhbnHecS7FowwA9TSjLNTfUwQXJPvX0NhCMwu",
      "tickets": [],
      "gains": [],
      "__v": 0,
      "nom": "ACHEMLAL_",
      "prenom": "MERYEM_",
      "tel": "0619562721"
    }
  ],
  "iat": 1572043952
}
```

You can read the `account.role` property to decide what to do in your application. [See the JWT spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) for more details about how to parse the JWT, or there may be a library available to do it for you.

Again, I'd caution you to never return the JWT in the API. You could always just expose it *without* the signing bits to make it unusable as an auth token (split it on the `.` characters and return the payload segment); then on the client side you only have to base64-decode the string. Or perhaps your API could do that decoding for you.

Comment: @Bravo's code to decode the JWT looks correct to me if you still want to go this route.

Comment: how can i use the token in all the website without exposing it in browser please ? using the split right ?

Comment: Change the API you're calling to get the auth details so that it returns _details from the token_, not the entire token itself. Your application shouldn't need the token itself; I'm assuming it's already being passed through HTTP cookies. It just needs to know the role and maybe other details.

Comment: thank you jacob, 
now my question was, how can i hide the form auth in render() when the role == user, do you have an idea about that ?

Comment: First you have to set some state in your component to represent their role. Then your render method will use that state to either render it or not render it.